# Generating new(fake) probability distributions based on many sample probabilty distributions

Tags: sampling, dataset, bootstrap, goodness-of-fit, random-generation

I wish to be able to generate new probability distributions that incorporate the characteristics of many sample distributions available to me.

I currently have data for the individual daily return of 5 different stocks over a one year time period.  I want to generate data for new (fake) stocks that 1)incorporates the general shape of a stocks daily return probability distribution, and 2) has unique qualities(such as a unique mean or variance) based on those 5 stocks making up my sample data.

My planned solution is as follows :

1. For each of my 5 sample data create a theoretical distribution. The theoretical distribution was found using the method provided by CT Zhu's answer as an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620471/fitting-empirical-distribution-to-theoretical-ones-with-scipy-python. All the resulting theoretical distributions for my data were  alpha distributions. This means for each of my 5 sample data i have 5 theoretical distributions (alpha distributions) and the values of the parameters that describe these theoretical distributions.
2. For each of my samples, use bootstrapping to create new samples and then fit it to an alpha distribution where i then record the theoretical distributions parameters. After this i will then have an individual probability distribution for each of the three parameters that describe an alpha distribution.
3. To generate a new probability distribution for the return of a new(fake) stock over a year, randomly select a value from each of the three probability distributions described above, and use these three parameters to create an alpha distribution.

I have two questions :

1. Is my solution valid,?
2. Will creating new distributions by randomly selecting a variable from each of the three probability distributions for the alpha distribution's parameters, lead to a probability distribution that resembles that of the sample data?

Comment: (1) why should the three parameters be independent? You need to estimate the joint distribution (2) are you sure bootstrapping is validated in the current setting? The data is made of time series, not of iid observations.